# Implementation of a crypto formula in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to implement in Python the formula in the image. The set B is a set of real numbers \$-1 \le t \le 1\$. Also, \$\mathbb{F}_2\$ is a set with the elements 0 and 1. \$y_i\$ is the \$i\$-th element of \$y\$. This formula is part of an iterative part of my program. The number of iterations is about 10K (over x) and n is 32. I tried a pre-computation approach. That is, I precomputed all \$f(y)\$ and put it in a numpy array, also I computed \$-1^{y_i}\$ and put it in a numpy array. See code below. But even with that, the computation takes approx 3s for the non-precomputation and n=24. When I tried to n=32 I get some memory issues due to the big arrays. My question is.

Can you help me to improve this code in terms of memory and time, please?

[image]

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
import galois


def precomputation_part(linear_layer_matrix, dim):
    y_shift = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: (i)>>j, ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint32)
    um=np.ones(((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint8);
    and_list = np.bitwise_and(y_shift,um, dtype=np.uint8)
    minus1_power_x_t = np.power(-1,and_list, dtype=np.int8)
    fy_matrix = evaluated_f_bool_matrix(and_list, np.array(linear_layer_matrix,dtype=np.uint8))
    boolean_function_0 = fy_matrix[0]
    return boolean_function_0, minus1_power_x_t

def evaluated_f_bool_matrix(and_components, input_matrix):
    t1 = time.time()
    mc = and_components.transpose()
    mal = input_matrix
    return np.matmul(mal,mc,dtype=np.uint8)%2

def create_ext_component_function(dim, boolean_function, input_lst, minus1_power_x_t):
    um_minus_minus1_power = ne.evaluate('1-minus1_power_x_t*input_lst')
    um_minus_minus1_power_prod = um_minus_minus1_power.prod(axis=1)
    boolean_function_times_prod = np.dot(boolean_function, um_minus_minus1_power_prod)

    return boolean_function_times_prod*(1/((2**dim)-1))-1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dim = 24
    f_matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
    boolean_function_0, minus1_power_x_t = precomputation_part(f_matrix, dim)
    ########The below two lines are executed several times
    x = np.array([i+1 for i in range(dim)], dtype=float)
    print(create_ext_component_function(dim, boolean_function_0, x, minus1_power_x_t))
```

Comment: A quick note: using `if __name__ == '__main__'` is great but you should consider putting all the chunk of code in a `main` function and then just call it under the if. (`if __name__ == '__main__': 
main()`)

Comment: 2**24 * 24 is about 402 MB of memory for just one of your matrices. Is this intended? Creating this is, on its own, fairly slow.

Comment: I failed to understand the connection between the input matrix and the computed boolean function. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @vnp I'm not sure if you were asking me or the OP. I was referring to `um` which isn't (?) the input matrix; it's part of the precomputation routine.

Comment: @Reinderien I was asking OP. It seems that keeping only those \$y\$s yielding true values of \$f(y)\$ would be beneficial. But as I said, I faild to understand the nature of \$f\$.

Comment: What is the F set and the F_2 set and the F_2^n set?

Comment: F_2 set with elements 0 and 1. F_2^n set of vector os length n, where the elements belongs to F_2